# Flutter - material search bar above Google map

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

Flutter beginner here with very limited experience so far. I am trying to replicate the Google Map App with a search bar floating above the Google map.

However, what confuses me is that when I search for existing examples, the examples will always build an obscure search bar from scratch with a text field or use a third party search bar. I am looking at:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchBar-class.html
https://m3.material.io/components/search/overview

but there is not useable solution / example that I can work with as of now. What trick should I use to make the out-of-the-box Flutter search bar work?

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SearchBar(
            hintText: 'ASDF',
// WHAT ELSE DO I NEED?
          ),
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
            compassEnabled: false,
            mapToolbarEnabled: false,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            mapType: MapType.satellite,
            initialCameraPosition: GoogleMapTools.cameraPositionFactory(center),
            markers: _markers.toSet(),
          ),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.3,
            minChildSize: 0,
            maxChildSize: 1,
            snap: true,
            snapSizes: [0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1],
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return Container(
                decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20)
                  )
                ),
                child: 
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 50,
                          child: Divider(thickness: 5),
                        ),
                        moreContent(context, 'ASDF'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              );
            },
        ),
       ]
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar(context, bottomNavigationBarTap),
    );
```